# Opening and closing DB connection when using multiple threads

Tags: java, sql, database, multithreading

I am updating my db from a couple of threads and am not sure where exactly to close the connection from. I am using Java JDBC.

```
Thread t= new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SwitchHandler shandler = new  SwitchHandler (da);
            shandler.portOverSubscriber(routingWrapper);
            CloseConnection();
        }
    });t.start();
```

Comment: Why don't you make each thread open and close its own connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of closing the connection try using a connection pool like [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)